# is this a valid id attributes ? if yes why can't javascript undersatand this

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, encryption

Due do some security purpose i want make id for element as `OUR_MISSIONIDxcR/+dvmUOfaxP4M2eutUg==` for this i have decrypt some string and aapend to id . But in case when i am trying to use this id to perform action , javascript restrict me for doing this.

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #OUR_MISSIONIDxcR/+dvmUOfaxP4M2eutUg==
```

However in jsp pages i have made element like this

```
<span id="#OUR_MISSIONIDxcR/+dvmUOfaxP4M2eutUg=="> </span>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/dus8eae6/ (Chrome, FF)

Comment: Why do you need to put sensitive data inside an HTML elements attribute, just curious?

Comment: @Giladd not working in mine chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

There are some rules in HTML4 to declare 'id':

- It **must** start begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").
- HTML5 is even more permissive, saying only that an id must contain at least one character and may not contain any space characters.

Some browsers might support use of '#' in ids or name tokens but I think you should avoid certain characters like

1. Periods
2. colons
3. #

as they have special meaning in CSS selectors, so you will have to escape those characters using a backslash in CSS or a double backslash in a selector string passed to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

As the [HTML4 documentation mentions](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name), the id tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods ("."). So, to respond to your question, no, that is not a valid id attribute value.

Edit: In the [HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) it says that it can contain any characters. But note, it also advises: "Identifiers are opaque strings. Particular meanings should not be derived from the value of the id attribute." So if you care about security, try to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to escape the non-alphanumeric characters.

> To use any of the meta-characters (such as
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar").

See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/